# How to split string to extract coordinates

Tags: java, android

I have a string that contains coordinate "42.262699 N 55.312947 E". I want to remove characters 'N' and 'E' and then split it into two spearate Xcoordinate and Ycoordinate strings.
I tried some regex but not able to make it work as I want. Kindly help.

Comment: You don't need regex. Just split by a space. Then you have coordinates and directions in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String cords = "42.262699 N 55.312947 E";
String[] split = str.split("\\s+"); // split by whitespace
//now we have array with every "word", 4 items

double Xcoordinate = Double.parseDouble(split[0]); // parsing to double
double Ycoordinate = Double.parseDouble(split[2]);

String X = split[1]; //"N"
String Y = split[3]; //"E"
```

you may need to use `try{ }catch()` for `Double.parseDouble(` as it may throw parsing exception